# I have two cells with different heights. When I remove the first one, the second one gets the height of the first one

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

### Some context

In this screen you can add and remove people. Not all fields are required, so the cell height is dynamic.

### The problem

If I add first a person with all the fields completed, then a second person with not all fields completed, and then I remove the first person, the second person takes the first place but with the layout of the first person

### IMPORTANT

After I remove the first person, if I scroll up until the remaining cell is off screen, then it fixes itself

### Code

This is the table source

```
namespace xXxx.xXxx.iOS
{
    public class SiniestroParticipantesSource : MvxTableViewSource
    {
        private readonly SiniestroParticipantesViewModel viewModel;

        public SiniestroParticipantesSource(UITableView tableView, SiniestroParticipantesViewModel viewModel)
            : base(tableView)
        {
            this.UseAnimations = true;
            this.AddAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimation.Top;
            this.RemoveAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimation.Middle;
            this.viewModel = viewModel;

            tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UINib.FromName(PersonaDenunciaCellView.Key, NSBundle.MainBundle), PersonaDenunciaCellView.Key);
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
            var itemPersona = this.viewModel.Personas[indexPath.Section];
            this.viewModel.AgregarCommand.Execute(itemPersona);
        }

        protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
        {
            var cell = (PersonaDenunciaCellView)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(PersonaDenunciaCellView.Key, indexPath);
            return cell;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
        {
            return this.viewModel.Personas.Count;
        }

        protected override object GetItemAt(NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return this.viewModel.Personas[indexPath.Section];
        }
    }
}
```

This is the cell view

```
namespace xXxx.xXxx.iOS
{
    public partial class PersonaDenunciaCellView : MvxTableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("PersonaDenunciaCellView");
        public static readonly UINib Nib;

        static PersonaDenunciaCellView()
        {
            Nib = UINib.FromName("PersonaDenunciaCellView", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        }

        protected PersonaDenunciaCellView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {

            this.DelayBind(() =>
            {
                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<PersonaDenunciaCellView, PersonaDenunciaItemViewModel>();

                set.Bind(btnRemove).To(vm => vm.RemoveCommand);

                set.Bind(lblNombre).To(vm => vm.Persona.Persona.Nombre);

                set.Bind(lblTipoDoc).To(vm => vm.Persona.Persona.TipoDoc.Descripcion);
                set.Bind(tipoDocVisibilityConst).For("Priority").To(vm => vm.Persona.Persona.Nrodoc).WithConversion("iOSVisibility", true);

                set.Bind(lblNrodoc).To(vm => vm.Persona.Persona.Nrodoc);
                set.Bind(nroDocVisibilityConst).For("Priority").To(vm => vm.Persona.Persona.Nrodoc).WithConversion("iOSVisibility", true);

                set.Bind(lblMailContacto).To(vm => vm.Persona.MailContacto);
                set.Bind(mailContactoVisibilityConst).For("Priority").To(vm => vm.Persona.MailContacto).WithConversion("iOSVisibility", true);

                set.Bind(lblTelContacto).To(vm => vm.Persona.TelContacto);
                set.Bind(telContactoVisibilityConst).For("Priority").To(vm => vm.Persona.TelContacto).WithConversion("iOSVisibility", true);

                set.Bind(lblLesionado).To(vm => vm.Persona.Lesionado).WithConversion("Lesionado");

                set.Bind(vehiculoVisibilityConst).For("Priority").To(vm => vm.Persona.Patente).WithConversion("iOSVisibility", true);
                set.Bind(viewVehiculo).For("Visibility").To(vm => vm.Persona.Patente).WithConversion("Visibility");
                set.Bind(lblPatente).To(vm => vm.Persona.Patente);
                set.Bind(lblCiaSeguroDesc).To(vm => vm.Persona.CiaSeguroDesc);

                set.Apply();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Cell ViewModel

```
namespace xXxx.xXxx.Core.ViewModels.Items
{

    public class PersonaDenunciaItemViewModel:MvxViewModel
    {
        private readonly IMvxMessenger messenger;
        private readonly IUserInteraction userInteraction;

        public string Index { get; set; }

        public PersonaDenunciaItemViewModel (SiniestroCarga.PersonaDenuncia persona, IMvxMessenger messenger, IUserInteraction userInteraction, string index)
        {
            this.messenger = messenger;
            this.userInteraction = userInteraction;
            this.Persona = persona;
            this.Index = index;
        }

        private SiniestroCarga.PersonaDenuncia persona;
        public SiniestroCarga.PersonaDenuncia Persona
        {
            get
            {
                return this.persona;
            }
            set
            {
                this.persona = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Persona);
            }
        }

        private ICommand removeCommand;
        public ICommand RemoveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return this.removeCommand = this.removeCommand ?? new MvxCommand(this.RemovePersona);
            }
        }

        private void RemovePersona()
        {
            this.userInteraction.Confirm("Are you sure?", () =>
            {
                this.messenger.Publish(new RemovePersonaDenunciaMessage(this, this.Persona, this.Index));
            }, null, "OK", "Cancel");
        }
    }

}
```

And that last messenger.Publish is subscribed to this on another ViewModel

```
OnRemovePersonaDenuncia = message =>
                {
                    var listPersonas = new ObservableCollection<PersonaDenunciaItemViewModel>(this.Personas);
                    listPersonas.Remove(this.Personas.First(p => p.Index == message.Index));
                    this.Personas = listPersonas;
                }
```

### Updates

Changing the implementation of RemoveCommand to this

```
this.Personas.Remove(this.Personas.First(p => p.Index == message.Index));
```

Makes that, when I press the remove button, the simulator closes without any error. The application trace on Xamarin Studio shows this

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:1700

Comment: Are you using Autolayout in your TableViewCells ? Also can you post your viewmodel ? Especially the RemoveCommand implementation

Comment: @wishmaster yes, I'm using AutoLayout. I will update the post now

Comment: @wishmaster updated

Comment: Can you try this: In OnRemovePersonaDenuncia change the implementation to  this.Personas?.Remove(message.Persona) ?

Comment: @wishmaster this.Personas and message.Persona are different types, so "cannot convert from xXxx.xXxx.Core.Models.Persona to xXxx.xXxx.Core.ViewModels.Items.PersonaItemViewModel"

Comment: I see just update to this instead: this.Personas?.Remove(this.Personas.First(p => p.Index == message.Index)

Comment: I have updated the post to show the results

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not calculate the height of the cells correctly when the content height is dynamic. That´s very annoying but you can override `GetHeightForRow` and `EstimatedHeight` in `SiniestroParticipantesSource` to calculate the exact height of each cell depending on the data:

```
public override nfloat EstimatedHeight(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) => 
    GetHeightForRow(tableView, indexPath);

public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var data = (PersonaDenunciaItemViewModel)ItemsSource.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
    var cell = (PersonaDenunciaCellView)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(PersonaDenunciaCellView.Key, indexPath);

    // TODO set the cell data manually (ignoring bindings)
    // i.e: **cell.lblNombre = data.Persona.Persona.Nombre**; // and every other field required

    cell.SetNeedsLayout();
    cell.LayoutIfNeeded();

    var size = cell.ContentView.SystemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UIView.UILayoutFittingCompressedSize);
    return NMath.Ceiling(size.Height) + 1;
}
```

Here´s an [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jxlbxi5ub72j2y/image.mov?dl=0) using the very same code.

Comment: Why should I ignore bindings?

Comment: Because you don´t want to wait for any binding to do its work. You want to asign values right away. This operation is just to calculate heights. Not related to mvvmcross bindings

Comment: I can't access the cell elements such as cell.lblNombre. "due to its protection level"

Comment: lblNombre is probably auto generated in the designer file. Expose it in by public UILabel LblNombre => lblNombre